# Soldered copper vs threaded copper at shower valve

Tags: plumbing, shower, bathtub, copper-tubing

I am replacing a shower faucet. The previous install soldered the copper to the shower valve but I am considering using threaded copper in case I ever need to replace it. What are the pros and cons of each type of install?[image]

Comment: When soldering the new valve make sure you disassemble the new valve so you don't ruin the internals from the heat used to solder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all my years, threaded or soldered, I've never replaced a valve with the same valve, and definitely not with the threaded connections. If you think about the logistics of unthreading a shower valve to reuse the connections, you'll see what I mean.

I've come to the conclusion that the threads are for convenience of installation, not re-use.

Comment: And to really make it replaceable he'd have to include unions in the connecting pipes, which would complicate things, and potential leak points.